# List replication problem from Hacker rank

Tags: functional-programming, scala

Problem:

Given a list, repeat each element in the list ***n*** amount of times.

Solution:

```
def listReplication(num:Int,arr:List[Int]):List[Int] = {
      arr.flatMap(each => (1 to num).map(n => each))
}
```

Need review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`scala.collection.generic.SeqFactory.fill(n:Int)(elem: =>A)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/SeqFactory.html#fill[A](n:Int)(elem:=%3EA):CC[A]) instead of your self written one:

```
def listReplication(num:Int,arr:List[Int]):List[Int] = {
      arr.flatMap(each => List.fill(num)(each))
}
```

Also note that listReplication is a nice candidate for generics:

```
def listReplication[A](num:Int,arr:List[A]):List[A] = {
      arr.flatMap(each => List.fill(num)(each))
}
```

That way you can also handle lists that contain something else than `Int`.